# Error when calling jquery/ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, textarea

I am trying to create a page that I can edit the contents of a `<textarea>` and when I click Submit, it should update mysql DB. When I click the submit button. Firebug is giving me this error:

NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument

Can anyone tell me why I am getting that error? Here is my code:

HTML

```
<form id="homeForm" method="post">
     <textarea cols="100" rows="20" id="hometext" name="hometext"><?php echo $pagetext ?></textarea>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Jquery/ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#homeForm').submit(function(){
    var homeText = $('textarea#hometext').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "PHPscripts/updateHomeText.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'hometext' : hometext},
        success: function(data) {}
    });
    return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to passe `data: {'hometext' : hometext}` but `hometext` isn't declared in your code. Did you mean `homeText` ?

Just a little mistake. Check the case and accord the variables names.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.. Thanks! That got rid of the error.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just because homeText is case sensitive.  Try changing:

```
data: {'hometext' : hometext},
```

to:

```
data: {'hometext' : homeText},
```

I also don' think you need the apostrophes around the first param, but I believe it will work either way.  Could be mistaken here.

Good luck.

Comment: No problem, glad we could help!